# Vuetify combobox not getting focus after clicking cancel on dialog

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a v-combobox component in my app. I have it to where I can type something in the input then @blur a check happens to see if the typed Item exists in the list or not. If it does not exist a modal opens up asking the user if they want to add it to the list.

I have it if the user clicks yes it is added to the list the problem I am having is if they click cancel and the dialog is closed focus should go back to the combobx input

When I try and set the focus I get the blue animation bar but no input cursor in the input of the combo box

I have set up a codesandbox example of my issue

[CodeSandbox Example of Issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-galileo-ycxw8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

I was wondering If i could get some help or pointers on why Im not getting the full focus to be able to type after clicking cancel on the dialog .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use $nextTick like this:

```
    closeConfirmationDialog() {
      // const comboBox = this.$refs[this.forInput];
      // comboBox.$el.querySelector("input").focus();
      this.showDialog = false;
      this.cancelDialog = true;
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$refs.categories.focus();
      });
    }
```